# Query involving join - combine data from 2 of our tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

We need to combine data from 2 of our tables - `active_deals` and `deal_display_controls`. The (relevant) columns in each of them are:

```
`active_deals` : `deal_id`, `region_code`
`deal_display_controls` : `deal_id`, `display_control_id`
```

The query needs to fetch all count of all the active deals having a given display_control_id and group them by their region_code (group by region code). Along with this, it also needs to group the active deals by region code (without the display_control_id constraint)

So, if the active deals tables looks like:

```
deal_id  region_code
   d1           US
   d2           CA
   d3           US
```

And the deal_display_controls looks like:

```
`deal_id`    `display_control_id`
   d1              dc1
   d2              dc1
   d3              dc2
   d4              dc1
```

Then for a given display control id = “dc1”
The query should output:

```
`region_code`    `count_of_active_deals_with_given_display_control_for_region_code   `count_of_active_deals_for_region_code`
  US                          1                                                                            2
  CA                          1                                                                            1
```

I could do this by splitting the above question into 2 parts and writing individual queries for each part:
Part 1: To get the active deals for a given display_control_id and group by region code
Query for the same:

```
select count(*), region_code from active_deals join deal_display_controls on active_deals.bin_deal_id=deal_display_controls.deal_id where deal_display_controls.display_control_id=0xc04e20724f5f49c9a285cb3c98d777b4 group by active_deals.region_code;
```

O/p:

```
`region_code`    `count_of_active_deals_with_given_display_control_for_region_code  
  US                          1                                                                                                                
  CA                          1
```

Part2: To get the active deals and group by region code
Query for the same:

```
select count(*), region_code from active_deals join deal_display_controls on active_deals.bin_deal_id=deal_display_controls.deal_id group by active_deals.region_code;
```

O/p:

```
`region_code`    `count_of_active_deals_for_region_code`
  US                          2
  CA                          1
```

I need to way to combine these 2 queries into a single query. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while counting you can add additional condition of `control_id`

```
select d.region_code
     , count(distinct d.deal_id) count_of_active_deals_for_region_code
     , SUM(c.display_control_id = 'dc1') count_of_active_deals_with_given_display_control_for_region_code
  from active_deals d
  left 
  join deal_display_controls c
    on d.deal_id = c.deal_id
group 
    by d.region_code
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904670/2

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select d.region_code,
       sum(ad.display_control_id = 1),
       count(*)
from active_deals ad join
     deals d
     on ad.deal_id = d.deal_id
group by d.region_code
```